# Openfaas common files during development

Tags: python-3.x, openfaas

I'm using the copy function to create reusable code in a common folder.
https://docs.openfaas.com/reference/yaml/#copy

I was reading most of the discussion before implementing this feature
[enter link description here](https://github.com/openfaas/faas-cli/issues/322)

and the PR
[enter link description here](https://github.com/openfaas/faas-cli/pull/744)

Can't find any information about how to solve the problem that the files from the common folder are missing during development.
how to fix the `Import "function.common.*" could not be resolved` during development.
I'm used to step through the code when reading it but the connection is not there and very the code is very error prone.